# Identity involving shifted Legendre coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics

For small values of $n$ ($2\leqslant n\leqslant 5$), the coefficients $a_k = (-1)^k{n\choose k}{n+k\choose k}$ of the shifted Legendre polynomial $\tilde{P}_n(x)$ satisfy the identity $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {ka_k}{(n+k)(2k+1)} = \frac{(-1)^n}{4n^2-1}.$ Does that identity hold for all $n$? If so, how might one prove it?

Comment: You don't want that $(-1)^n$: it should be just $-1/(4n^2-1)$.

Comment: This bears some resemblance to Catalan numbers.  Maybe you can find and tweak a similar relation among Catalan numbers to get a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we write the right side of Robert's identity as 
$$(-1)^n\frac{(\nu-2)(\nu-4)\cdots(\nu - 2n+2)}{(\nu+2)(\nu+4)\cdots(\nu+2n)},$$
we see that the identity is a partial fraction expansion of a proper rational function. (This is a littler simpler if we replace $\nu$ with $2\nu$.)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat more generally, Maple 18 says that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{(-1)^k k}{(n+k)(2k+v)} {n \choose k} {{n+k} \choose k} =
 -{\frac {\Gamma  \left( v/2+2 \right) \Gamma  \left( n-v/2 \right) }{
 \left( v+2 \right) \Gamma  \left( 1-v/2 \right) \Gamma  \left( 1+v/2+
n \right) }}
$$
which for $v=1$ gives you the desired identity.

It appears that Maple is using Zeilberger's algorithm.